# Setting ArcMap attribute dialog split orientation to horizontal by default?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.0, editing, fields-attributes

When you open ArcMap 10, and open the attribute window (editor toolbar), the attribute dialog is split vertically.

You can press the toggle button to split the dialog horizontally.

I always use it split horizontally, so how can I set it to that by default?

Comment: After some testing, in contrast; no matter where I put my editor-attributes window, or what state I leave it in, it always starts with a horizontal split. (ArcMap 10, SP4).

Comment: @GIS-Jonathan, Thanks for your help. Why don't you make this a regular answer, so I can give you credit (upvote) for your help?

Comment: I don't feel I've answered the question, hence commenting. It may be possible, probably some hidden registry setting or something. You can vote up comments incidentally (they don't give reputation, but I have enough of that already :-) ).

Answer (score 2):

In the interest of closing off this question, I'll paraphrase the comment from @GIS-Jonathan.

It doesn't seem that there is a way to have a default state for the attributes window. It always defaults to the horizontal split. I believe this is still the case for 10.6 and is unlikely to change in ArcGIS Desktop.

However, it looks to be resolved in ArcGIS Pro.